# problem in ajax while passing parameter..404 not found

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-2.0

ajax 404 not found while passing a parameter...but it works when i didnt pass a parameter..plz help. onchange i want the items of selected event.

view

```
        echo $this->Html->image("/images/loader/loader.gif", array("alt" => "", 'class' => 'loader', 'id' => 'ajximg2', 'style' => 'display:none'));
            echo $this->Form->input('item_id', array('label' => 'Competition Name', 'empty' => '-----Select-----', 'id' => 'item'));



controller:
public function event_item_ajax($eventId) {
        $items = $this->Item->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Item.event_id' => $eventId)));
        $this->set('items', $items);
    }

Jquery:
$(function() {
    $( "#event").change(function( event ) {
        $("#ajximg2").show();
        alert($(this).val());
        $.ajax({    
            url: '/results/event_item_ajax/' +escape( $(this).val()),
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'HTML',
            success: function (html) {
                $("#item").html(html);
                $("#ajximg2").hide();
            },     
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Put `let eventValue = $(this).val()` beside `alert` and use it like this: `'/results/event_item_ajax/' +escape(eventValue)`

Comment: Put parameters on `data: yourDataObj` inside `ajax({`.

Comment: tnx @AliFarhoudi